# How do i use intent to go to next activity from listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I have created listview with custom adapter to load my images and text into the listview. The next thing i would like to do is to load the next activity using intent once i click on the listview items. However,the app crashes once i click on it. Any idea where my error is?

The code in the main activity till the onItemClickListener is working as intended. I have tested this using a toast once i click on the items. However, once i apply intent, the app crashes and is not able to proceed to the next activity.

MainActivity.java is as follows

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SingaporePlacesofInterest extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
SearchView sv;

private int[] images = new int[]{
        R.drawable.us,
        R.drawable.gardens,
        R.drawable.mbs,
        R.drawable.ns,
        R.drawable.orchard,
        R.drawable.riversafari,
        R.drawable.rws,
        R.drawable.singaporeflyer};

private String[] names = new String[]{
        "Universal Studios",
        "Gardens by The Bay",
        "Marina Bay Sands",
        "Night Safari",
        "Orchard Road",
        "River Safari",
        "Resorts World Sentosa",
        "Singapore Flyer"};

private String[] type = new String[]{
        "Excitement",
        "Sightseeing",
        "Excitement",
        "Night Life",
        "Shopping",
        "Sightseeing",
        "Excitement",
        "Sightseeing"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_singapore_places_of_interest);

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);

    final Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this, getPOI());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

            return false;
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int selected, long id) {

            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayPOI.class);


            intent.putExtra("poi", names);
            intent.putExtra("images", images);
            intent.putExtra("type", type);*/
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}


public ArrayList<POI> getPOI()
{
    ArrayList<POI> POIS = new ArrayList<POI>();
    POI p;

    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        p = new POI(type[i], names[i], images[i]);
        POIS.add(p);

    }

    return POIS;
}
}
```

DisplayPOI.java is as follows

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayPOI extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
ImageView img;
String names [];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_poi);

    /*to retrieve the intent*/

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    names = intent.getStringArrayExtra("poi");

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

     tv.setText("This is a " + names);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

**Logcat of crash**

**
02-02 16:42:23.899 3934-3934/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
02-02 16:42:23.900 3934-3934/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-02 16:42:23.950 3934-3934/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest.DisplayPOI}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1932)
                                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
                                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
                                                                                                at com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest.SingaporePlacesofInterest$2.onItemClick(SingaporePlacesofInterest.java:106)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1165)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3134)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4061)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3820)
                                                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11725)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2955)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:445)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1828)
                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3292)
                                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:407)
                                                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11964)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4776)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4590)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4331)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6
02-02 16:42:23.951 3934-3934/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-02 16:42:23.974 3934-3934/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest, PID: 3934
                                                                                          android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest.DisplayPOI}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1932)
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
                                                                                              at com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest.SingaporePlacesofInterest$2.onItemClick(SingaporePlacesofInterest.java:106)
                                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
                                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1165)
                                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3134)
                                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4061)
                                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3820)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11725)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2955)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:445)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1828)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3292)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:407)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11964)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4776)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4590)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4331)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
02-02 16:42:23.975 3934-3934/com.wong.desmond.singaporeplacesofinterest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6616)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6577)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6745)
                                                                                              at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @DWing logcat please. Also avoid using application context to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: add the logcat showing the crash, so we can help you

Comment: Have added in the logcat. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that you declare the new activity in the manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".DisplayPOI"></activity>
```

Comment: Have tried your suggestion. but it is still unable to load. Thanks for the suggestion in any case.

Comment: from the logcat issue is Unable to find explicit activity class DisplayPOI, Ali has shared the fix for this. If you could share the new logcat please.

Comment: You are right, Ali and Tanni! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DWing can you vote up the answer , to help others when they look at the question .. and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

in the manifest file, define activity like this:

```
<application
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <activity
        android:name="<activity name with full package name>"/*ex. 
com.example.android.MainActivty*/
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Call Intent from Activity like this:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this,Receiver_class_name.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Replace "Receiver_class_name" with activity name.

Remember, for this to work, Both the Activities must in the same package, otherwise you have to mention activity name with the full package.

Example:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,com.example.android.custom.MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here, "com.example.android.custom" is the package of the activity.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Birju! Works perfectly.